# Convert plot offset along the y-axis to a sign function [-1;1]

Tags: functions, algorithms, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I’m not sure that I clearly enough reflected the essence of a small problem in the title of the topic, but I’ll try to reveal its essence in the question itself.

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28-x%29%2B0.1*sin%2810*x%29%2B0.05%2C-1*%28exp%28-x%29%2B0.1*sin%2810*x%29%2B0.05%29%20from%20x%3D0%20to%2010)

[image]

We have two functions.

If the function is shifted more to the positive region (up along the $y-axis$), then we "mentally associate the $+1$ sign with it, if it is negative (down the $y-axis$), then we" mentally associate the $-1$ sign with it".

If both the positive and negative regions are approximately the same, then we must switch between $-1$ and $+1$. Is there a continuous function that implements this operation, including in real time mode and those cases when the analytical description of the function is unknown?

**EDIT:**
Let me be more specific: 
I need a function that extracts a constant component of the signal proportional to the displacement along the y-axis.
The signal continuously changes in time, therefore, it is necessary to extract the DC component in real time. For example, from this functions:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28-t%29%2B1*sin%2820*t%29%2B1%2C-%28exp%28-t%29%2B1*sin%2820*t%29%2B1%29%20for%20t%3D0%20to%2010)

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%28-1%2Cmin%28x%2C1%29%29)?

Comment: I adjusted the question. Added specifics.